Roles Authorization not working for Razor Pages site using AddNegotiate
The Short Version:
I have a ASP.net core Razorpages app Authenticating against Windows Users via .addNegotiate(). Roles are then assigned based on AD Groups via a claims transformer, lets call one of the added Roles "Admin". And Additional policy "SiteAuth" has been set up based on these roles.
Authorizing against the "SiteAuth" policy  a razor page using [Authorize(Policy = "SiteAuth")] works, however [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] does not work and redirects to the Unauthorised page. Simplifying to [Authorize] does work.
Further more if (User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Value == "Admin")) also works as expected.
I've observed the claims transform being hit via a break point when hitting the page showing that the user should be authorized and the Claim has been added.
What have I missed or done wrong that [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] does not Authorize as expected?
Longer Tech Details Version:
Program.cs - relevant parts:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("SiteAuth", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(
        context => context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && (new string[] { "SuperAdmin", "Admin", "User" }).Contains(claim.Value))));
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    o.Conventions.Add(new ActionRouteConvention());
});

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

/**** Other Services Added/Configured ***/


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/errors/{0}");
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapGet("/debug-claims", (ClaimsPrincipal user) =>
{
    return Results.Ok(user.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }));
}).RequireAuthorization();
app.Run();

ClaimsTransformer
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly SiteSettings _siteSettings;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    private readonly ILogger<ClaimsTransformer> _logger;

    public ClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, SiteSettings siteSettings, ILogger<ClaimsTransformer> logger)
    {
        _siteSettings= siteSettings;
        _context= httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var groups = wi.Groups;

        if (groups != null)
        {
            foreach (var group in groups) //-- Getting all the AD groups that user belongs to---  
            {
                try
                {
                    string groupName = string.Empty;
                    if(_siteSettings.AdminGroups.TryGetValue(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString(), out groupName))
                    {
                        if(!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Value == groupName))
                        {
                            //var claim = new Claim("RAAuth", groupName);
                            //wi.AddClaim(claim);
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Adding role {groupName} to claims.");
                            var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, groupName);
                            //wi.AddClaim(claim);
                            ci.AddClaim(claim);
                            //claim = new Claim(wi.RoleClaimType, group.Value);
                            //wi.AddClaim(claim);
                        }
                    }                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }    
}

Debug Info
Dumping the claims to screen gives:
{
    "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
    "value": "Admin"
},
{
    "type": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
    "value": "SuperAdmin"
},

Which strongly suggests the roles have been applied.
The role name was copy and pasted to the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] to eliminate typos
Hopefully I've messed something simple here.

Can you use AddTransient for registering the claim transformer and check.

It is because when using windows authentication the "RoleClaim Name" is different. Just use like following:
...
var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
...
var claim = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, groupName);
...

Then the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]will work.
To clarify:
ClaimTypes.Role :  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" 
ci.RoleClaimType: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid"
